# PHP fullcalendar each day box lower the height

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am dealing with the PHP plugin -- fullcalendar master.
Can I adjust the height of the box?
How? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show some code and elaborate the same. Also show what you've tried till now and it'll be helpful. Please follow this before you post future questions : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you type the exact phrase from your question, *"fullcalendar master. Can I adjust the height of the box"* into google, the first two results are documentation for FullCalendar's [`height`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/height)` and [`contentHeight`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/contentHeight) options. In the future, consider spending a bit more time researching, and have an attempt included in your question. Remember, this is not a code-writing service, but rather a Q&A!

Comment: Thanks Tyler Roper, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set height using

```
 contentHeight: '50px',
```

Comment: Thanks, Bhumi. I found the solution.

Comment: Hi Bhumi, it doesnt work in my case. I typed  height: 550 in the js part, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to adjust the UI of Full Calendar of any external libraries. Use inspect element and check the class and id by pointing on particular elements. And then perform the change accordingly. You can use inline CSS as well. It will be good if you use "!important" in CSS file. 
     example

```
.classname
 {
   height: 10px !important;
 }
```

or

```
 #id      {
   height: 10px !important;
  }
```

Comment: `It will be good if you use "!important" in CSS file.` Using css `!important` is never _good_, its always a workaround. In general i suggest generally avoiding `!important` at all cost. Still there are some cases youll need it in some cases e.g. overwriting inline styles from javascript you cant change, but generally speaking a healty approach imo is to stay away as far as you can from `!important`.

Comment: Yes Fabian Schöner is absolutely right but just to make sure your changes are working test with "!important". Thanks for pointing out.